# Ordered SUM aggregation with sometimes percent value (based on calculated sum to this row) in row instead of common value

Tags: postgresql

For simple example we have tables with values like this

```sql
create table added
(
    amount      numeric(78, 0),
    event_index numeric(78, 0)
);
insert into added
values (100, 1),
       (500, 4)
;
create table reduce
(
    amount      numeric(78, 0),
    event_index numeric(78, 0)
);
insert into reduce
values (50, 2),
       (100, 5)
;
create table interest
(
    percent     numeric(78, 0),
    event_index numeric(78, 0)
);
insert into interest
values (10, 3),
       (20, 6)
;
```

This query with union all:

```sql
select *
from (
         select 'added' event_type, amount, event_index
         from added
         union all
         select 'reduce' event_type, amount, event_index
         from reduce
         union all
         select 'interest' event_type, percent, event_index
         from interest
     ) as all_ordered_events
order by event_index
;
```

Will return

```
added,100,1
reduce,50,2
interest,10,3
added,500,4
reduce,100,5
interest,20,6
```

And I need to calculate it with this formula:

```
100(added) - 50(reduce) + 10%(intereset) + 500(added) - 100(reduce) + 20%(intereset)
```

I should have sum equal to: **546**.

I tried something like this:

```sql
with all_events as (
    select *
    from (
             select 'added' event_type, amount, event_index
             from added
             union all
             select 'reduce' event_type, amount, event_index
             from reduce
             union all
             select 'interest' event_type, percent, event_index
             from interest
         ) as all_ordered_events
    order by event_index
)
select sum(
               CASE
                   WHEN event_type = 'added' THEN amount
                   WHEN event_type = 'reduce' THEN -amount
                   WHEN event_type = 'interest'
                       THEN amount -- Wrong. Here the problem, how to get percent of aggregated sum
                   END
           )
from all_events
;
```

But when `event_type` is `intereset` I'm not sure how to say to postgres that this is a percent value and you should not to sum common **10** value, but should calculate 10 percent of already calculated sum to this row.

**Is it possible somehow?**

Updated 1:
Looks like with this view and recursive query I'm a little bit closer to what I want:

```sql
CREATE VIEW all_ordered_events AS
select event_type, amount, event_index
from (
         select 'added' event_type, amount, event_index
         from added
         union all
         select 'reduce' event_type, amount, event_index
         from reduce
         union all
         select 'interest' event_type, percent, event_index
         from interest
     ) as all_ordered_events
order by event_index
;
```

Recursive query:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT 'initial'         as t,
           0::numeric(78, 0) as amount,
           0::numeric(78, 0) as event_index,
           0::numeric(78, 0) as total
    UNION ALL
    select all_ordered_events.event_type,
           all_ordered_events.amount::numeric(78, 0),
           all_ordered_events.event_index::numeric(78, 0),
           (
               CASE
                   WHEN event_type = 'added' THEN (r.total + all_ordered_events.amount)
                   WHEN event_type = 'reduce' THEN (r.total - all_ordered_events.amount)
                   WHEN event_type = 'interest'
                       THEN (r.total + (r.total / 100 * all_ordered_events.amount))
                   END
               )::numeric(78, 0) as total
    from all_ordered_events
             JOIN r ON r.event_index + 1 = all_ordered_events.event_index
)
SELECT *
FROM r
;
```

Result:

| type | amount | event_index | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| initial | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| added | 100 | 1 | 100 |
| reduce | 50 | 2 | 50 |
| interest | 10 | 3 | 55 |
| added | 500 | 4 | 555 |
| reduce | 100 | 5 | 455 |
| interest | 20 | 6 | 546 |

But still not exactly what I want.. I need just last value (**546**), because in real world tables I also have something like `entity_id` in each those tables by which I need to `group by` result for get this specific **sum** for each `enitity`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like I found how it can be solved:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
    SELECT 'initial'         as t,
           0::numeric(78, 0) as amount,
           0::numeric(78, 0) as event_index,
           0::numeric(78, 0) as total
    UNION ALL
    select all_ordered_events.event_type,
           (
               CASE
                   WHEN event_type = 'added' THEN all_ordered_events.amount
                   WHEN event_type = 'reduce' THEN -all_ordered_events.amount
                   WHEN event_type = 'interest'
                       THEN (r.total / 100 * all_ordered_events.amount)
                   END
               )::numeric(78, 0) as real_amount, -- in case of percent
           all_ordered_events.event_index::numeric(78, 0),
           (
               CASE
                   WHEN event_type = 'added' THEN (r.total + all_ordered_events.amount)
                   WHEN event_type = 'reduce' THEN (r.total - all_ordered_events.amount)
                   WHEN event_type = 'interest'
                       THEN (r.total + (r.total / 100 * all_ordered_events.amount))
                   END
               )::numeric(78, 0) as total
    from all_ordered_events
             JOIN r ON r.event_index + 1 = all_ordered_events.event_index
)
SELECT t, amount, event_index
FROM r
```

Will give me:

| t | amount | event_index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| initial | 0 | 0 |
| added | 100 | 1 |
| reduce | -50 | 2 |
| interest | 5 | 3 |
| added | 500 | 4 |
| reduce | -100 | 5 |
| interest | 91 | 6 |

And where we have type **interest** we see that the amount now based on percent calculated from total sum before this **event_index**.

0 + 100 - 50 + 5 (10% from 100 -50) + 500 - 100 + 91 (20% from 100 - 50 + 5 + 500 - 100) = 546

Now I can simple **sum(amount)** column.